# Does struct hostent have a field "h_addr"?

Tags: linux, hostent

I encountered the following code snapshot:

```
struct hostent *hp;
 hp = my_gethostbyname(localhost);
    if (hp == NULL) {
       ls_syslog(LOG_ERR, I18N_FUNC_FAIL, fname, "my_gethostbyname()");
       return -1;
    }
    strcpy(localhost, hp->h_name);

    memcpy(&addr, hp->h_addr, hp->h_length);
```

I am rather confused by the last statement, the declaration of struct hostent is like this:

```
struct hostent {
   char *h_name;       /* official name of host */
   char **h_aliases;   /* alias list */
   int h_addrtype;     /* host address type */
   int h_length;       /* length of address */
   char **h_addr_list; /* list of addresses */
};
```

It doesn't have a field named "h_addr", but the code did can compile, can anyone tell me why? thanks.

Comment: I'm getting an error on VSCode that says, "struct "hostent" has no field "h_addr" but it compiles and runs fine.  The code was copy pasted from here:  https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15213-f99/www/class26/tcpclient.c

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You missed this bit right under it:

```
#define h_addr h_addr_list[0] /* for backward compatibility */
```

So no, there is no problem.

Answer (score 4):

In the [GNU libc manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Host-Names.html) (or [see here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#index-struct-hostent) for the entire libc manual all on one page) they say:

> Recall that the host might be connected to multiple networks and have different addresses on each one

They also provide the `h_addr` variable which is just the first element of the vector `h_addr_list`.

Comment: One might wonder: "how long is the `h_addr_list` array?" Answer: Iterate down it until you find a `NULL` ptr. An address string inside the `h_addr_list` which consists of nothing but a `NULL` ptr indicates the end of the list. The [GNU libc documentation link (see here for it all one 1 pg)](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#index-struct-hostent) states that too: `The vector is terminated by a null pointer.`

Answer (score 2):

`h_addr` is not [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX). See [POSIX netdb.h](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/netdb.h.html). Using `h_addr` could result in `error: ‘struct hostent’ has no member named ‘h_addr’`. Portable code should use `h_addr_list` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the `h_addr` macro is on some systems only visible if you define  `_BSD_SOURCE` and/or `_DEFAULT_SOURCE` before including header files.